# How do I grep the CiviCRM universe?

Tags: extension

I'd like to remove some deprecated code from CiviCRM core, but I'm not sure if it might be used by other extensions in the CiviCRM universe. Is there a way to search the code of all known extensions?

Comment: @LukeStewart that's exactly what I needed. Feel free to add an answer and I'll upvote/accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use build kit to generate a repo including the civi "universe"  https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/universe/

```
civibuild create universe
```

or

```
mkdir ~/src/universe
fetch-universe ~/src/universe
```

could be worth checking extension usage to see if there are any widely used ones that don't make the cut to get included.

Happy grepping!

Comment: ripgrep is amazing for this sort of thing. Universe is around 5GB today, and I was able to grep for a regex match in php files in under 1s. It's in Debian and Fedora as package `ripgrep` or use the releases: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases